# Unexpected code clean up formatting behavior for IF statements. Is there a setting missed?

Tags: c#, resharper

- Resharper Ultimate 2017.3
- VS 15.6.2

I have code clean up setup to change braces for single statements:

[image]

and then braces configuration for IF statements as follows:

[image]

however given some code such as:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c;

    if (a == 1 && b == 1)
        c = b;

    //This one will format incorrectly
    if (a == 1 && b == 1)
    {
        c = b;
    }
}
```

when I do the code clean up I get:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c;

    if (a == 1 && b == 1)
        c = b;

    //This one will format incorrectly
    if (a == 1 && b == 1) c = b;
}
```

Note how the last IF statement appears on a single line instead of the body on its own line like the one above.

I *think* this is a change in behaviour but don't have an old version of R# to refer back to. Has anyone got a settings combination for 2017.3 that will make:

- Single line IF statements always have their body appear on their own line AND
- Remove braces when the block is only a single line

Comment: In Rider, under the Line Breaks and Wrapping section of the C# code style, there's an option called "Place simple embedded statement on same line" under the Arrangement of Embedded Statements sub group. I believe the setting will be similarly named in R#, and you'll want it set to Never.

Comment: @JonathonChase Works just like a bought one! If you would like to make that an answer I will approve same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm basing this off of the settings in JetBrain's Rider rather than R#, but I believe the settings and organization are the same.

You're looking for a setting named 'Place simple embedded statements on same line'. It is found under the C# Code Style settings in the Line Breaks and Wrapping section, sub-group 'Arrangement of Embedded Statements'.